# CSS to set A4 paper size

Tags: css, printing, print-preview

I need simulate an A4 paper in web and allow to print this page as it is show on browser (Chrome, specifically). I set the element size to 21cm x 29.7cm, but when I send to print (or print preview) it clip my page.

See this [**Live example**](https://jsfiddle.net/2wk6Q/1/)!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  font: 12pt "Tahoma";
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page {
  width: 21cm;
  min-height: 29.7cm;
  padding: 2cm;
  margin: 1cm auto;
  border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.subpage {
  padding: 1cm;
  border: 5px red solid;
  height: 256mm;
  outline: 2cm #FFEAEA solid;
}

@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 0;
}

@media print {
  .page {
    margin: 0;
    border: initial;
    border-radius: initial;
    width: initial;
    min-height: initial;
    box-shadow: initial;
    background: initial;
    page-break-after: always;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="book">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="subpage">Page 1/2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="subpage">Page 2/2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think I'm forgetting something. But what would it be?

- **Chrome**: clipping page, double page (*it's just what I need it to work*)
- **Firefox**: it works perfectly.
- **IE10**: believe it or not, it's perfect!
- **Opera**: very buggy on print preview

Comment: The correct answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34018790/293856

Comment: Possible dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341485/how-to-make-a-html-page-in-a4-paper-size-pages

Comment: [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=603559#c64) about this

Answer (score 334, accepted):

I looked into this a bit more and the actual problem seems to be with assigning `initial` to page `width` under the `print` media rule. It seems like in Chrome `width: initial` on the `.page` element results in ***scaling*** of the page content if no specific length value is defined for `width` on any of the parent elements (`width: initial` in this case resolves to `width: auto` ... but actually any value smaller than the size defined under the `@page` rule causes the same issue).

So not only the content is now ***too long*** for the page (by about *`2cm`*), but also the page padding will be slightly more than the initial *`2cm`* and so on (it seems to render the contents under `width: auto` to the width of *`~196mm`* and then scale the whole content up to the width of *`210mm`* ~ but strangely exactly the same scaling factor is applied to contents with any width smaller than *`210mm`*).

To fix this problem you can simply in the `print` media rule assign the A4 paper width and hight to `html, body` or directly to `.page` and in this case avoid the `initial` keyword.

#### [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mturjak/2wk6Q/1949/)

```
@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 0;
}
@media print {
  html, body {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
  }
  /* ... the rest of the rules ... */
}
```

<sup>**This seems to keep everything else the way it is in your original CSS and fix the problem in Chrome (tested in different versions of Chrome under Windows, OS X and Ubuntu).**</sup>

Comment: Hey @MartinTurjak, i tweaked your fiddle to a US Letter version, in case anyone's interested. 

http://jsfiddle.net/2wk6Q/2957/

Cheers!

Comment: For the blank print pages problem, just remove all the  .page { } class below the  @media print { } and it will get sorted. That class is totally unnecessary

Comment: This (at least, the fiddle example) no longer appears to work on Chrome 92 (MacOS 11.4). I see white margins on both sides of the print area :(

Answer (score 54):

**CSS**

```
body {
  background: rgb(204,204,204); 
}
page[size="A4"] {
  background: white;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
@media print {
  body, page[size="A4"] {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<page size="A4"></page>
<page size="A4"></page>
<page size="A4"></page>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/oyvhm4p0/)

Comment: side note: `<page>` is not a [valid custom HTML element name](https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/#valid-custom-element-name)

Comment: Seems to work. But `box-shadow: 0;` doesn't work (at least in Chrome), it should be `box-shadow: none;`. The two margin declarations can also be combined into `margin: 0 auto 0.5cm;`.

Answer (score 50):

https://github.com/cognitom/paper-css seems to solve all my needs.

## Paper CSS for happy printing

> Front-end printing solution - previewable and live-reloadable!