# Detecting printed page size with CSS media queries

Tags: css, printing, media-queries

My app generates printed reports by creating an invisible iframe and then printing it.  My latest in a depressingly long list of problems I'm trying to solve is optimizing the CSS for different printed page sizes.  IE9 *seems* to work a bit (but has other issues, like ignoring @page { margin:... }), but no luck at all on FF or Chrome.

My code looks like this:

```
@media print and (width: 210mm) and (height: 297mm) {
   ... stuff for A4 size ...
}

@media print and (width: 8.5in) and (height: 11in) {
   ... stuff for US letter size ...
}
```

Neither of these rules is being matched, ever, in Chrome or FF.  I also tried device-width and device-height, and those didn't work either (they seemed to be reporting the absolute maximum sizes of the printer, rather than the page size).  I can't figure out what value "width" and "height" are returning, is there a way to tell?

Is there a reliable way to detect printed page size using media queries?  I'm pretty close to concluding that there is simply *no* way to control printing in any consistent way across browsers, and throwing in the towel on this.

Comment: I wonder if it's having issues with an exact width/height. Have you tried changing it to something like `max-width` or `min-height`?

Comment: Just tried it, no go.  Consider:

`<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    @media (min-width: 8in) {
        body { font-weight: bold; }
    }
    @media (min-width: 10.5in) {
        body { font-style: italic; }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
here is some body text
</body>
</html>`

Here, the CSS is triggered as I resize the window, but once I go to print nothing triggers anymore (tested in Chrome).

Comment: Many years later.....

I'm having this issue too.  I'm generating pages with SVG technical diagrams and I'd like to change the layoutbased on the paper size selected.  In my case, I need to check for 11x17, 18x24 and 24x36 paper sizes to adjust the size (scale) of the diagrams as well as resizing stroke-widths and text heights appropriately.

Does anybody have any idea how to do this?

Comment: [this `paper-css` github project](https://github.com/cognitom/paper-css) seems to have looked deeply into such issues.

Comment: Have you tried any page directives like <style>@page { size: letter }</style>? Instead of trying to do breakpoints? Letter is 8.5x11 inch.

There are other options:

A5, A5 landscape
A4, A4 landscape
A3, A3 landscape
letter, letter landscape
legal, legal landscape

Comment: How about using % for the width property? Have you targeted for each browser and then included the media queries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS to set A4 paper size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649943/css-to-set-a4-paper-size)

Answer (score 1):

Just try this code May be this can fixed your problem.

```
<page size="A4"></page>
```

Css

```
@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 0;
}
page {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
page[size="A4"] {  
  width: 210mm;
  height: 297mm; 
}

@media print {
  body {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
    background: rgb(204,204,204); 
  }
}
```

Comment: The above code should work. For A4 landscape the CSS would be: `page[size="A4"][layout="landscape"] {
  width: 29.7cm;
  height: 21cm;  
}`