# Use CSS Detect Page Orientation in Printing

Tags: css, printing, orientation

I want to use CSS style to detect the page orientation in printing and then apply different styles when user choose different orientations (landscape or portrait).

```
@media print{ /*portrait*/  /*landscape*/}
```

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Wait...how would this look different when printed? It's not clear what the use-case is for this, Are you trying to do this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361384/detecting-printed-page-size-with-css-media-queries?rq=1

Comment: @Paulie_D It seems like the same general idea, except rather than testing for specific sizes, it's just testing if the width is longer than the height or vice versa.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `orientation: ...` media selector. Here's an example:

```css
@media print and (orientation: portrait) {
    /* Your code for portrait orientation */
}
@media print and (orientation: landscape) {
    /* Your code for landscape orientation */
}
```

Comment: You could nest the media queries
`@media print {
@media (orientation: landscape){
}
@media (orentation: portrait) {
}
}
`