# How to change paper size when printing in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Sorry for a too simple question, but I cannot find an answer for a long time. I am saving an iFrame in Chrome as pdf using this jQuery code:

```
$("#ifr").get(0).contentWindow.print();
```

Everything works perfectly fine, but Chrome always takes the Letter format for the output. I need to increase the paper size or define a custom paper size.

There are many references that **Chrome should take the paper size from the default printer** in Win 7. But changing the default printer printing options (paper size, layout etc) doesn't affect Chrome printing - it always takes the Letter format regardless of the default printer settings.

From where does Chrome take the printing page size settings? How can I change it?

Thanks

Comment: From a browser? Not possible

Comment: This is a duplicate question, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649943/css-to-set-a4-paper-size this will answer your question.