# Can I use CSS to format A4 printout with header and footer on every page?

Tags: css, html

I've created an HTML page that is intended to be printed on A4 (8.5"x11").  The HTML can span one or more pages, depending on the query results. I don't have any page breaks coded into the HTML.
Can I use CSS to force the page size to 8.5"x11" and print a header at the top of each page and a footer at the bottom of each page?
~~~Tracy

Comment: Yes, you can.  You need to look into CSS media queries.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649943/css-to-set-a4-paper-size