# While printing preview issues, using @media query print css

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I m trying to print two shipping labels in one A4 sheet using @media query print css. Following is the code i'm trying but it is coming as one shipping label half in one sheet another one shipping label in another sheet. I need to fit in both the shipping labels in one A4 sheet.

Can someone pls help me or guide me how to do this, to fit two shipping labels in one A4 sheet using @media print css. Following is the code i m using.

```
<style media="print">
    .print { display:none; }
    body {
    width: 470px !important;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: -270;
    margin-left: 100px;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
</style>
```

thanks in advance...!!!!

Comment: what is width and height values? for which screen?

Comment: Following is the page height n width        .awb_body {
        width: 550px !important;
        }   .height {
        min-height: 100px;
        }

Answer (score 0):

You're styling the body very small and you aren't using the @page CSS rule to define the page size, which may prove to be the problem. See [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16649943/2495717) for other pages that might help you.

**edit**

You might also need to use `page-break-inside`, see [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/).

Comment: thanks for the answer but still not able to solve my problem here. I think i m missing something anyhow thanks for your suggestion

Comment: What html and css are you using on the labels themselves?

Comment: it looks fine after entering ref no but i need it to be fine when i click on print... i m not getting it right after clicking on print preview. I m using html5 n css3 on the labels as well