# CSS to set 21 cm width and 9.33 cm height paper size

Tags: html, css

I have a trouble when i have to print to paper with a width of 21 cm and a height of 9.33 cm or A4 size divided into three parts (it is the payment receipt).
I try with the following css but was not succesful

```
    @media print {
        @page { size:21 cm 9.33 cm; size : landscape; }
    }
```

is there any suggestion to resolve the issue
thank you

Comment: Maybe you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649943/css-to-set-a4-paper-size

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1cm is equal to 37px. I've just google it for you.

Comment: Converting pixels to centimetres depends on the DPI (dots per inch) of the media displaying the image.