# HTML and CSS set printing page size to half letter

Tags: html, css

I need to set a layout to be printed using paper of half letter size (215mm height and 139mm width).
I have tested many css parameters such as

```css
@page {
  size: 139mm 215mm;
  margin: 0;
}

@media print {
  @page {
    size: 139mm 215mm;
  }
}

html {
  width: 139mm;
  height: 215mm;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 139mm;
  height: 215mm;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="height: 215mm; width: 139mm; border:solid grey 1px;">
    <!-- My content -->
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

But when I print using Control+P, I always get a Legal vertical size page.

**How can I set this custom size to be printed in any browser?**

Comment: Be inspired to this similar solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649943/css-to-set-a4-paper-size

Comment: I have tried that but still giving an A4 print preview size with my div in the left upper corner

Answer (score 0):

Beside defining `size` you also need to define `height` and `width` for `@page`. I updated your code and placed it below, I hope that solves your problem.

#### Key part:

```
@page {
  size: 139mm 215mm;
  height: 215mm;
  width: 139mm;
  margin: 0;
}
```

#### Snippet:

```js
window.print();
```

```css
@page {
  size: 139mm 215mm;
  height: 215mm;
  width: 139mm;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  width: 139mm;
  height: 215mm;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 139mm;
  height: 215mm;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="height: 215mm; width: 139mm; border:solid grey 1px;">
    <!-- My content -->
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

#### [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmo2jt7z/4/)