# Bonitasoft - printable form

Tags: bonita

I want to create printable form in bonitasoft process. The form should include some attributes from business data. In my forms I want to have a button, that will print the form. Is it possible to do it ? if yes can you tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi [Kalmakhelidze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11571455/s-kalmakhelidze)

Yes it can be done easily!

For Business Data you can use :

1. External API in UI Designer [Doc ExternalAPI](https://documentation.bonitasoft.com/bonita/7.10/variables#toc1)
2. Context (To display contextual information of the task or the process instance in a form, you can leverage the business data and document references made publicly available through the context)
   [Doc Context](https://documentation.bonitasoft.com/bonita/7.10/contracts-and-contexts#toc3)

And to add print capability as well :
. Duplicate Question [Stack Print a4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649943/css-to-set-a4-paper-size)