# Set footer display data in last page when print data table javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a trouble on how can I set automatically my footer to display in last page to meet the proper printing of pages, but it seems it has a conflict below. Is there any idea or solution on how to display the footer in the last page?
Is there any expert can suggest or help me, please see the attachment thanks in advance!

[image: Attachment]

> html

```
<button onclick="printDiv();">Print it</button>

<table class="report-container" name="table" id="table">

<thead class="report-header">
<th colspan="9">
  <div class="titles">Title Header <br></div>
</th>
<tr>
  <td>ID Number</td>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Barangay</td>
  <td>Sex</td>
  <td>Sector</td>
  <td>Amount</td>
  <td>Signature/thumb</td>
  <td>ID &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
  <td>Date Received</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr >
    <th ><div class="footer"></div></th>
    <th colspan="2">  <div class="footer">TOTAL NO. OF PERSONS  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </div> 
</th>
    th colspan="2" ><div class="numbers">20</div></th> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <th class="footer"></th>
    <th colspan="2" class="footer"><div class="footer">TOTAL AMOUNT NEEDED &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </div> 
</th>
    <th colspan="2" > <div class="numbers">Amount</div></th>    
</tr>
                        
<tr>
<th></th>
<th colspan="2"><div class="certify">I hereby certify that each person whose name appears on this 
 DATA DATA are entitled to cash assistance</div></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th colspan="6"><div class="certify">I certifiy on my official oath that I have this day ____ of 
 _______________________ pain in DATA DATAD ATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DAATA,</div></th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody class="report-content">
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

> javascript

```
function printDiv() {
// Make footer visible on last page only
let tbl = document.getElementById('table');
let footer = tbl.getElementsByTagName('tfoot')[0];
footer.style.display = 'table-row-group';
tbl.removeChild(footer);
tbl.appendChild(footer);

// Make header visible on first page only
let title = document.querySelector('.titles');
let newTitle = title.cloneNode(true);
newTitle.style.textAlign = "center";
newTitle.style.fontWeight = "bold";
tbl.prepend(newTitle);
title.remove();

var divToPrint = document.getElementById('table');
var htmlToPrint = '' +
'<style type="text/css">' +
'table td {' +
'border:1px solid #dddddd;' +
'padding:8px;' +
'}' +

'table  {' +
'border-collapse: collapse;' +
'width: 100%;' +
'}' +

'</style>';
htmlToPrint += divToPrint.outerHTML;
newWin = window.open("");
newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
newWin.print();
newWin.close();
}
```

> Css

```
    @media screen {
    .noPrint {}
    .titles {
    display: none;
    }
    .footer {
    display: none;
    }
    }
    @media print {
   .noPrint {
    display: none;
    }
   .title {}
   .footer {}
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the sign-off part as a row within the `tfoot` tag itself?  That should keep those two parts together.

Comment: @ATD Thanks for your response what do you mean sign-off?

Comment: Sorry, that's what I call any block at end of a document where someone has to sign it.

Comment: @ATD I don't have any idea about sign-off, do you have example? please thank you

Comment: Eh?  You already have one - the bit at the end that says "I hereby certify...."  I don't know what you would call that part of your document - I call it a sign-off.

Comment: @ATD for now my solution ,inorder to compressed the data to fit in every pages I just need to adjust my scale print like this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhtI1.png) but is there any solution to automate the scaling I guess ?when the footer data is not correctly display.

Comment: Have a look at: [print on A4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649943/css-to-set-a4-paper-size)  This shows you a technique for sizing a document.

Comment: @ATD I think it can't solve the problem through giving A4 size of my pages. Can this link can help me ?with my previous problem above? or do you have any idea?I'm just confused with this one thank you for your response

Comment: OK - firstly, you need to check the HTML - the first row of `tfoot` is missing a `<` in front of the 3rd `th` tag.  Secondly, you already have everything in the footer - the person count and the sign-off (or whatever you want to call it).  If you want those to be printed only on the last page, you will have to remove them from the table and put them underneath.  Create a new table and simply shift the tfoot content into that instead.

Comment: @ATD  thanks for your response you mean , I need to create another table? one table has no tfoot? and the another one it has tfoot?

Comment: @ATD  thanks for your response you mean , please help me with this one , I've tried but the result is the same .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your comment, yes, one table has no `tfoot` and one table only has a `tfoot`

Like this (also correcting for the missing `<`):

```html
<table class="report-container" name="table" id="table">

<thead class="report-header">
<th colspan="9">
  <div class="titles">Title Header <br></div>
</th>
<tr>
  <td>ID Number</td>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Barangay</td>
  <td>Sex</td>
  <td>Sector</td>
  <td>Amount</td>
  <td>Signature/thumb</td>
  <td>ID &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
  <td>Date Received</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="report-content">
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="report-content-cell">
    <div class="main">
      fas
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table>
<tfoot>
<tr >
    <th ><div class="footer"></div></th>
    <th colspan="2">  <div class="footer">TOTAL NO. OF PERSONS  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </div> 
</th>
    <th colspan="2" ><div class="numbers">20</div></th> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <th class="footer"></th>
    <th colspan="2" class="footer"><div class="footer">TOTAL AMOUNT NEEDED &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </div> 
</th>
    <th colspan="2" > <div class="numbers">Amount</div></th>    
</tr>
                        
<tr>
<th></th>
<th colspan="2"><div class="certify">I hereby certify that each person whose name appears on this 
 DATA DATA are entitled to cash assistance</div></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th colspan="6"><div class="certify">I certifiy on my official oath that I have this day ____ of 
 _______________________ pain in DATA DATAD ATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DATA DAATA,</div></th>
</tr>
</tfoot>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna try this