# How to get Puppeteer PDF generation to match HTML document exactly, in regards to page breaks?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer to generate PDF files, using static HTML as the source:

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setContent(html); //html is read in from the file system

const pdf = await page.pdf({
    format: 'A4',
    printBackground: true,
    preferCSSPageSize: true
});
```

The same HTML is also shown to front-end users of my application, so they can get an exact preview of the content, before downloading the PDF.

To match the size of an A4 piece of paper, I am using CSS to set the `<body>` tag of the HTML to a certain width and height, accounting for page margins in the process.

So for example, my CSS may look like this:

```
@page {
    margin: 1cm; //tells Puppeteer to print the PDF with a 1cm margin
}

body {
    width: 19cm; // (21cm width minus 1cm margin on each side)
    height: 27.7cm // (29.7cm height minus 1cm margin top and bottom)
}
```

The issue I am facing is with regard to page breaks; Puppeteer sometimes splits the bottom content into separate pages.

For example, this is what the HTML looks like, for the bottom of the A4 page representation that the front-end user sees.

[image]

As you can see, there is clearly enough space for the bottom row of text to fit, it is not being cut off.

However, Puppeteer prints the PDF like so:

[image]

i.e. it splits the text into two separate pages.

This behavior also seems to be very erratic; I have noticed at times (e.g. with different text/paragraph lengths), it doesn't split the content into separate pages.

Do you have any idea as to why Puppeteer is splitting the text? I have gone through the documentation but cannot seem to find any solutions for this.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5277 help? Esp the **non-flexbox style**

Comment: FWIK, puppeteer uses the "print as pdf" functionality of Chrome, under the hood, to generate the PDFs. Do you see the same behavior when you open the page manually in Chrome and print it to PDF? Based on this, you could see if the issue should be further checked in Puppeteer or Chrome.

Comment: @badcoder , would you be able to provide minimal reproducible example html and your environment like os and browser?

Comment: @badcoder please share your HTML code as well.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that there is a mismatch between your CSS settings for the page-size, and the A4 pagesize that chrome is using to print.

Have a look at the following question/answer and specifically the CSS settings in the approved answer.

[CSS to set A4 paper size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649943/css-to-set-a4-paper-size)

The proposed solution is to make use also of the [print media rule](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_printing.htm).

They have a specific demo with the following code:

```
@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 0;
}
@media print {
  html, body {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
  }
  /* ... the rest of the rules ... */
}
```

I modified their demo slightly to include your Lorem Ipsum bulleted text. You can view it @ http://jsfiddle.net/x7s2cntj/1/ .

Click run to see the result, or try it in headless chrome using `puppeteer`.

I removed the snippet from stack overflow because it seems some additional CSS is being applied inside the snippet window.