# HTML div with A4 dimensions is larger than A4

Tags: html, css

I set the size of a parent div to A4 (`size="21cm 29.7cm"`). However, in Chrome print preview, with A4 and no margins, the HTML page won't fit on A4. I have to scale it to 80%.

Is there something in my HTML causing this? I expected the `size="21cm 29.7cm"` to force the page to be A4.

UPDATE I found this:

[CSS to set A4 paper size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649943/css-to-set-a4-paper-size)

And tried the below CSS, but not working:

```
@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 0;
}
@media print {
  html, body {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!Doctype>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .background
    {
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    .text
    {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      width: 1449px;
      height: 2050px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;" size="21cm 29.7cm">
    <img src='page0022.jpg' class="background"/>
    <img src='0022.svg' class="text"/>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to include a css reset like https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ otherwise look around device pixel ratio

Comment: Different devices have different DPIs.

Comment: @NVRM I pasted those styles at the top of my CSS style sheet but it doesn't seem to have changed anything.

Comment: @WaisKamal I'm a total noob here. I just want to convert my html to A4 (to print)

Comment: If the above CSS `@page` solutions are not working it is likely an issue with the size of your images. You need to make sure they abide by the A4 dimensions and do not overflow the page.

Comment: @justinseibert It seems to be a problem with Chrome. In Firefox it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Read about size:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size

**Add these `code` to your `HTML` file:**

```
<div class="page">...</div>
```

**Add these `code` to your `CSS` file**

```
@page {
    size: 21cm 29.7cm;
    margin: 30mm 45mm 30mm 45mm;
     /* change the margins as you want them to be. */
}

@media print {
    body{
        width: 21cm;
        height: 29.7cm;
        margin: 30mm 45mm 30mm 45mm; 
        /* change the margins as you want them to be. */
   } 
}
```

In case you think you really need pixels **(you should actually avoid using pixels)**, you will have to take care of choosing the correct DPI for printing:

- 72 dpi (web) = 595 X 842 pixels
- 300 dpi (print) = 2480 X 3508 pixels
- 600 dpi (high quality print) = 4960 X 7016 pixels

Yet, I would avoid the hassle and simply use **cm** (centimetres) or **mm** (millimetres) for sizing as that avoids rendering glitches that can arise depending on which client you use.

Comment: I use the pixels because I have an SVG which I have resized and laid over an image. Using pixels was the only way I could align the text and the image.

Comment: Read about a paper A4 sizes in pixels: https://www.papersizes.org/a-sizes-in-pixels.htm

Comment: I have needed your background and text image in SVG full link URL because your short (relative) URL is not working my Editor

Answer (score 0):

You should define `size` within an `@page` rule in your CSS stylesheet. It is not intended to be an attribute as you have done in your example.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page

```css
@page {
  size: A4;
}
```

`size` as an attribute is used to define the width of `<input>` and `<select>` elements, either by pixels or number of characters depending on `type`

Comment: Okay, have pasted that in my CSS file but hasn't changed. Do I need to set anything else in that page rule too, or A4 should suffice?

Comment: Set the margin to 0cm and then 5cm but it doesn't seem to be making a difference. I'll paste the CSS in my Q.

Comment: Try removing the `height` on your `.text` class or changing those dimensions to be %-based as the pixel size may be overflowing the A4 dimension