# CSS: How to set div specific print settings Letter and A4 depending on what paper user picks in print

Tags: css, printing

I need to line up images to a template but the layout differs for A4 and Letter. How do I set Paper specific settings for example

```
@media print [A4] { 
   .img {
      height: 40mm;
      margin: 17mm 6mm 0mm 5mm; 
      padding:0px !important;
      display: inline !important;
   }
}

@media print [Letter] { 
   .img {
      height: 42mm;
      margin: 29mm 4mm 0mm 2mm; 
      padding:0px !important;
      display: inline !important;
   }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649943/css-to-set-a4-paper-size

Check here probably you gonna find solution.

Comment: @Emre I don't want to set the paper size to A4 

I need CSS settings for A4 and Letter so when a User prints to an A4 it positions the images in certain location to line up with the A4 template 

If they print in US Letter it likewise positions the images to conform to the Letter template

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a pick list in the page as follows

```
<select id="paperSize"><option>A4</option><option>Letter</option></select>
```

then in JS

```
   $("#paperSize").on("change", function() {
      var paperSize = $(this).val();
      $("body").removeClass("A4").removeClass("Letter").addClass(paperSize);      

      Array.from(document.styleSheets).forEach(ss => {
          Array.from(ss.rules || ss.cssRules).forEach(rule => {
            if (rule instanceof CSSPageRule) {
              rule.style.size = paperSize.toLowerCase() + " portrait";
              console.log("New rule size: " + rule.style.size);
            }
          });
      });
   });
```

Then for CSS I can customise the layout depending on the paper size selected. The images layout is 2 x 14 images to one page

```
@page {
   size: portrait;
}

.imgContainer {
   position: relative;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 0fr);
}
   
/************************* Page Break Control *************************/
.img {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid; 
}

.imgDiv:nth-of-type(14n) {
  page-break-after: always;
}

/************************* A4 Settings *************************/
body.A4 .imgContainer {
  margin-left: 10mm!important;  
}

body.A4 .imgDiv:nth-child(14n + 1), body.A4 .imgDiv:nth-child(14n + 2) {
  margin-top: 14mm !important;
}

body.A4 .img {
  height: 42mm;
  margin: 15mm 4mm 0mm 5mm; 
  padding:0px !important;
  display: inline !important;
}

/************************* Letter Settings *************************/
body.Letter .imgContainer {
  margin-left: 10mm!important;  
}

body.Letter .imgDiv:nth-child(14n + 1), body.Letter .imgDiv:nth-child(14n + 2) {
  margin-top: 26mm !important;
}

body.Letter .img {
  height: 42mm;
  margin: 8.8mm 8mm 0mm 5mm; 
  padding:0px !important;
  display: inline !important;
}
```

my HTML structure is as follows

```
<div class="imgContainer">
   <div class="imgDiv"><img class="img" src="..."></div>
   <div class="imgDiv"><img class="img" src="..."></div>
   <div class="imgDiv"><img class="img" src="..."></div>
   <div class="imgDiv"><img class="img" src="..."></div>
   <div class="imgDiv"><img class="img" src="..."></div>
</div>
```